# I can't get the stop function to work in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a .swf file that I'm trying to use in my program. I don't want it to loop, just to stop on the first frame and only change frames when I tell it to. This works when I put the .swf file on the stage and tell that specific instance to stop(). But I need it to be a Movie Clip that's linked to an AS3 file. When I do that, stop() doesn't work anymore and it just keeps looping.

```
        mybrick = new Brick(0, 0);
        addChild( mybrick );
        mybrick.stop();
```

It doesn't give me any errors or anything, but it just keeps looping instead of stopping. For some reason when I go to "Convert to Symbol" and "Export for ActionScript" (which is how I made all my other objects follow their code) the stop() function no longer works. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Ok, here's the main file (I cut out the parts related to other objects because they're not affecting Brick and otherwise this would be pretty long)

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


public class RetrievoidGame extends MovieClip
{


    public var mybrick:Brick;

    public function RetrievoidGame()
    {


        mybrick = new Brick(0, 0);
        addChild( mybrick );
        mybrick.stop();



        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);

        var newTimer = new Timer( 1 );
        newTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, everyFrame );
        newTimer.start();

    }
```

And here's the Brick.as file:
            package
            {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;

```
    public class Brick extends MovieClip
    {


        public function Brick(myX, myY) {

            x = myX;
            y = myY;


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Is the class file continuously controlling the asset using `gotoAndPlay`? If that is the case, calling `stop()` isn't going to work.

Comment: I don't have gotoAndPlay in my code. I've tried calling stop() from the parent as you see above, and I've also tried putting stop() in Brick's constructor. I've also tried gotoAndStop(1) and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Does the brick movieclip have code in its timeline? Check that for errors.

Comment: No, I was told that it was bad to put code in the timeline. All my code is in .as files. It's not giving me any error message, it's simply looping when I tell it to stop()

Comment: Ok if there isn't any code in your timeline (please note that if there is any code anywhere in the timeline that has compiled with errors, your animations could all be on a continuous loop) then you will have to post more code so we can see where it may be coming from. Currently this won't be enough to go off of.

Comment: Ok if you are **not** manipulating `mybrick` in `everyFrame()` or `keyPressed()` then that code is perfectly fine. Can you upload your .fla if it isn't sensitive?

Comment: How do I upload the .fla file? I've never actually used this site much and don't see a place to do that. Or did you mean upload it to an external site and post the link?

Comment: It would have to be elsewhere, you cannot currently upload to stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, this should work: http://en.file-upload.net/download-8684190/RetrievoidGame.fla.html

Comment: I think I found it, brick has a child that's doing the animating. change `mybrick.stop()` to `mybrick.myblox.stop()`

Comment: That made it stop, thank you! "myblox" is what I named the original instance of the swf file when I was testing it, and I guess it remembered that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put stop(); in the first frame of the *MovieClip's* timeline. Use gotoAndPlay() from the parent when you want the MovieClip to move.

Comment: It's highly likely given the users details on the issue that this isn't the answer, the user has called a stop() already and it continues to loop.

Comment: How do I write code in the timeline? I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I can't figure out how to open that.

Comment: Well, where's the code for the .swf? Are you using Flash?

Comment: I should have asked: where's the .fla for the swf?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop Brick, because loop animation for him that you made, in another inner MovieClip? If you have inner MovieClips, you also should stop them. Give them some name on the timeline, like: myAnimation and stop them. `myBrick.myAnimation.stop()`

If it hard to you, use this code snippet, it will stop your Brick for sure, add these methods to the Class Brick:

```
override public function stop():void {
    super.stop();
    stopMovies(this);
}

private function stopMovies(movie:MovieClip):void{
    var i: uint, len:uint = movie.numChildren, child:MovieClip;
    for(i; i < len; ++i){
        child = movie.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if(child != null){
            child.stop();
            stopMovies(child);
        }
    }
}
```